# Python Breaking a While Loop

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am kinda new to Python and new to this website. I would like any assistance with my code. I am trying to break the loop when the user inputs a value but I am having trouble with it. I am doing a chat bot project for my school.

```
while ans:
        user_input = input("How are you?: (or press enter to quit) ")
        user_input = ''.join(ch for ch in user_input if ch not in exclude)
        user_words = user_input.split()
```

Comment: *"I would like any assistance with my code"* - Stack Overflow is not for "any assistance", it's for specific, answerable questions about programming problems. Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Have you tried `break`? ...it's not quite clear what your problem is.

Comment: what's the limit for exiting this loop, and what's `exclude` this may be missing some more code.

Comment: my problem is the user is in the infinite loop for asking "How are you?" and I am trying to edit the code so the question isn't asked every time.

Comment: that case you want to have the input outside of the loop and then `break` out

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for any input then you wouldn't need the while loop, Python will pause the program whilst it waits for a user input.

```
user_input = input("How are you?: (or press enter to quit) ")
user_input = ''.join(ch for ch in user_input if ch not in exclude)
user_words = user_input.split()
```

Alternatively if you want to wait for a specific value, you would need to set a condition to break the loop.

```
ans = True
while ans != "Quit":
    user_input = input("How are you?: (or press enter to quit) ")
    user_input = ''.join(ch for ch in user_input if ch not in exclude)
    user_words = user_input.split()
    if user_input == "Quit":
        ans = "Quit"
```

or

```
while ans:
    user_input = input("How are you?: (or press enter to quit) ")
    user_input = ''.join(ch for ch in user_input if ch not in exclude)
    user_words = user_input.split()
    if user_input == "Quit":
        break
```